# Textbox id is not accessible in the javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

I have this textbox indside a datalist

```
tr>
    <td><h5>Email</h5> <asp:TextBox ID="tb_email" CssClass="tb_orderByPhn" runat="server" /> </td>
</tr>
```

And a button to call javascript as

```
  <tr>
    <td> <asp:LinkButton id="btn_order"  class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-success btn_rad " OnClick="btn_order" OnClientClick=" return validate_order()"   runat="server" >Order now <i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right  " ></i></asp:LinkButton></td>
</tr>
```

On the above button click i am calling a javascript function.Upto this it is good but it won't recognize a textbox id why?

```
 function validate_order() {

    alert("ok");
    var name = document.getElementById('<%=tb_email.ClientId%>').value;
    alert(name);

}
```

It gives the error: The name 'tb_email' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Which Asp.Net version are you using? If .NET>=4 then use ClientIDMode = "static" on asp.net textbox and give it a try. Because asp.net may change the control ID when it render them to client appending some reference ids etc.

Comment: check the rendered html of the page in browser, and see what id it is creating.

Comment: Wow..the id shows `ccont_Dl_products_tb_email_0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which Asp.Net version are you using? 
If ASP.NET>=4.0 then use ClientIDMode = "Static" on asp.net textbox and give it a try. Because otherwise ASP.NET change the control ID when it render them to client-side by concatenating parent naming container with the ID value of the control etc.

Refer to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

try below code :

```
function validate_order() {

  alert("ok");
  var name = document.getElementById('tb_email.'+'<%=ClientId%>').value;
  alert(name);

}
```